# Graph API access for Office 365, Sharepoint & One Drive

Tags: sharepoint, o365security-compliance

Is there any API/ PowerShell command available to get SharePoint / exchange online / one drive admin portal configuration settings.

E.g. to list DLP, Anti malware policies etc.